# Software Updater crashes

Tags: lubuntu, update-manager

My lubuntu software updater seems to have troubles installing certain update packages.

After booting, it shows me the list of required updates, but when I try to install them, it terminates directly after showing the "Installing updates..." progress bar. Without any error message. 
Sometimes I can install the updates by randomly unchecking some packages from the list.
So maybe there is a problem with some sources? Unfortunately I dont know much about Ubuntu.
Also, with sudo apt-get update I can install some of the updates, but not all.

Is there a way to find out why this is happening? Or does anyone already know a solution?

Thanks!

EDIT:
sudo apt-get update results in:

> http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83,2 kB]
>   Hit:2 http: //archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Hit:3 http: //de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Hit:4 http: //ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/thinkpad-extras/ubuntu bionic
>   InRelease Hit:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates
>   InRelease              Hit:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   bionic-backports InRelease            Ign:7
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
>   Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release 
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] Reading package lists... Done
>   E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu
>   bionic Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a
>   repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
>   default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>   configuration details.

sudo apt-get upgrade:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done The following
>   packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>   linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic Use
>   'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. The following packages have been
>   kept back:   configure-trackpoint:i386 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed,
>   0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Note: I put some space in the links, as I am not allowed to post so many links...

Comment: @user535733 done :) there also seems to be a problem with the repositories...

Comment: Problem #1: Dead source (*Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]*). [Remove the source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911)

Comment: Problem #2: Held package (*The following packages have been kept back: configure-trackpoint:i386*). Tell us everything you know about that package, and why you installed it.

Comment: #1: Hmm I just tried to (with the Software & Updates GUI), but it doesnt react. Is there another way to remove the source?

Comment: #2 I have a lenovo thinkpad with a trackpoint and tried to configure its speed. I a tutorial (long ago, I dont remember which one) I was asked to install it....

Comment: I linked to EIGHT answers to remove a source, so check that link again and keep trying. If you don't use that trackpoint package anymore, then uninstall it.

Comment: @user535733 Oh, sorry, I didnt read that! I had to go to the sources.list.d folder but now I removed the dead source.

Comment: Thank you for the links! update and upgrade both dont give any errors now.
I installed the kept back configure-trackpoint package and the software updater sais everything is up to date! I will check if it will install new updates smoothly. If not I will ask for your help again :) Thank you so much, solving it wasnt actually difficult, I just didnt know where to start.

Comment: Very happy to read that you solved it!